# Should a cookie authkey be changed on each login?

Tags: authentication, cookies, yii2

I am using `Yii2` which saves an `authkey` in a cookie if the user wants their login information saved for next time.

Should this key be updated on each login or is it safe to allow this key to be persistent?

The reason I ask is if that cookie is stolen does the attacker then have access to the website?

Comment: I'm changing `authkey` only when user changes his password.

Comment: Does these mean if the cookie is stolen then is can be used to access the website? Also duration is only stored in the cookie this can easily be manipulated.

Comment: As far as I know as long as user's `authkey` and application's `cookieValidationKey` is not changed it is possible.

Comment: May be yii documentation link will help for you. Please refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/yii2/2945/cookies#t=20161011131526939891

Comment: `authkey` used for auto login function, if you can change it each login, auto login will not work if users use multiple browsers.

Comment: I guess with all auto login features there is an inherent security risk, this is just something I have to weigh up.